# std::find return a class that I can't acesses functions

Tags: c++, vector

I come from C/C# language and now I'm trying to learn about C++ and his standards functions.

Now, I'm creating a class called `IMonsterDead`. I will have a `std::vector<IMonsterDead*>` with `N` monsters.

Example:

```
class IMonsterDead {
public:
    IMonsterDead(int Id)
    {
        this->_Id = Id;
    }

    virtual void OnDead() = 0;

    int Id() const {
        return _Id;
    }
private:
    int _Id;
};
```

One class which implements that class:

```
class MonsterTest : public IMonsterDead {
public:
    MonsterTest(int generId)
        : IMonsterDead(generId)
    {
    }

    virtual void OnDead()
    {
        std::cout << "MonsterTesd died" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Ok, if I access directly everything works fine. But I'm trying to use `std::find`.

Full program test:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<IMonsterDead*> monsters;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        monsters.emplace_back(new MonsterTest(1000 + i));
    }

    int id = 1033;
    std::vector<IMonsterDead*>::iterator result = std::find(monsters.begin(), monsters.end(), [id]( IMonsterDead const* l) {
        return l->Id() == id;
    });

    if (result == monsters.end())
        std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
    else
    {
         // Here I want to access OnDead function from result
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So I need to access `OnDead` function from `result` but I can't. Intellisense doesn't show anything for me. The result exists.

How can I access that function? Have another better way to do that?

Comment: `std::vector<IMonsterDead*>::iterator result = ...` --> `const auto result = ...` - much nicer :)

Comment: Result is an iterator, if you dereference it (*result) that becomes the pointer again. PS: unique_ptr is really interesting

Comment: Which line is giving you the issue?  What is the exact text of the error the line causes?

Comment: I agree @JesperJuhl. But for now, Im trying to learn every step of C++ and trying to be verbose Thx anyway.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `std::find_if`?

Comment: @JVApen (*result)->OnDead you mean?

Comment: @NathanOliver just edited the thread

Comment: @Kevin for example, or better use an extra variable

Comment: @Bob__ I will see `find_if`. I don't know yet, Im learning, thx

Comment: @JVApen worked with (*result)->OnDead() But it's an ugly code, do not you think? Its only way?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_Id`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks!! It's ok use `_id` for example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `std::find_if()` instead of `std::find()`.  `std::find()` is for finding an element with a specific value, so you have to pass it the actual value to find, not a user_defined predicate.  `std::find_if()` is for finding an element based on a predicate.

Either way, if a match is found, dereferencing the returned iterator will give you a `IMonsterDead*` pointer (more accurately, it will give you a `IMonsterDead*&` reference-to-pointer).  You need to then dereference that pointer in order to access any members, like `OnDead()`.

You are also leaking memory.  You are not `delete`'ing the objects you `new`.  And when dealing with polymorphic types that get deleted via a pointer to a base class, the base class needs a `virtual` destructor to ensure all derived destructors get called properly.

With that said, you are clearly using C++11 or later (by the fact that you are using `vector::emplace_back()`), so you should use C++11 features to help you manage your code better:

- You should use `std::unique_ptr` to wrap your monster objects so you don't need to `delete` them manually.
- You should always use the `override` keyword when overriding a virtual method, to ensure you override it properly.  The compiler can catch more syntax errors when using `override` than without it.
- You should use `auto` whenever you declare a variable that the compiler can deduce its type for you.  Especially useful when dealing with templated code.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

class IMonsterDead {
public:
    IMonsterDead(int Id)
        : m_Id(Id)
    {
    }

    virtual ~IMonsterDead() {}

    virtual void OnDead() = 0;

    int Id() const {
        return m_Id;
    }

private:
    int m_Id;
};

class MonsterTest : public IMonsterDead {
public:
    MonsterTest(int generId)
        : IMonsterDead(generId)
    {
    }

    void OnDead() override
    {
        std::cout << "MonsterTest died" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IMonsterDead>> monsters;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        // using emplace_back() with a raw pointer risks leaking memory
        // if the emplacement fails, so push a fully-constructed
        // std::unique_ptr instead, to maintain ownership at all times...
        monsters.push_back(std::unique_ptr<IMonsterDead>(new MonsterTest(1000 + i)));

        // or:
        // std::unique_ptr<IMonsterDead> monster(new MonsterTest(1000 + i));
        // monsters.push_back(std::move(monster));

        // or, if you are using C++14 or later:
        // monsters.push_back(std::make_unique<MonsterTest>(1000 + i));
    }

    int id = 1033;
    auto result = std::find_if(monsters.begin(), monsters.end(),
        [id](decltype(monsters)::value_type &l) // or: (decltype(*monsters.begin()) l)
        {
            return (l->Id() == id);
        }

        // or, if you are using C++14 or later:
        // [id](auto &l) { return (l->Id() == id); }
    );

    if (result == monsters.end())
        std::cout << "Not found" << std::endl;
    else
    {
        auto &monster = *result; // monster is 'std::unique_ptr<IMonsterDead>&'
        monster->OnDead();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Bob__ yes.  I added it

Comment: Thanks for all advices @RemyLebeau. About virtual destructor, what's the right way to implement? I will see about `decltype` too and another questions

Comment: @KevinKouketsu That is a question that should be asked in a separate post.

Answer (score 2):

Iterators are an interesting abstraction, in this case to be reduced to pointers.

Either you receive the pointer to the element or you get an invalid end.

You can use it as a pointer: `(*result)->func();`

You can also use it to create a new variable:

```
IMonsterDead &m = **result; 
m.func();
```

This should give the same assembly, both possible.

Comment: `IMonsterDead *m = *result; m->func();` would make more sense in this situation

Comment: Same for me, I like references over pointers when it can't be nullptr

Comment: Thanks for the answer @JVApen. I appreciate it. I know you help me on comments before but Answer's it's a little more complete.